# why an item is selected in the dropdown?

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I have a drop-down as follows

```
<asp:Label runat="server" Text="Available Items"></asp:Label>
<asp:DropDownList runat="server" ID="ddItems"  />
```

Here is how data is populated in this dropdown.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.ddItems.Items.Add(new ListItem("first item", "1"));
            this.ddItems.Items.Add(new ListItem("second item", "2"));
            this.ddItems.Items.Add(new ListItem("third item", "3"));
            this.ddItems.SelectedIndex = -1;
        }
```

Since SelectedIndex is set to -1, I expect no items to be selected but first item is showing up in the drop down.

[image]

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Wouldn't you have an item in the dropdown labelled 'please select' (or some other message) to indicate nothing is selected?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

-1 does not refer to a position in the list, therefore you need to add an item with default text or empty string.

```
Protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // You can set the first list item text to empty string as well
        this.ddItems.Items.Add(new ListItem("select an item", ""));
        this.ddItems.Items.Add(new ListItem("first item", "1"));
        this.ddItems.Items.Add(new ListItem("second item", "2"));
        this.ddItems.Items.Add(new ListItem("third item", "3"));

        //This is no longer required as the default selected index is 0
        this.ddItems.SelectedIndex = 0;
    }
```